# Automatically Copy Sheet 1 A1:A2 to Sheet 2 A1:A2 When Sheet1 A1:A2 Changes

Tags: vba, excel

Objective: If any values in A1:A2 on sheet 1 change, then the values in A1:A2 on sheet 2 should automatically update with these values. The following sheet 1 event handler fails to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim target As Range
Set target = Range("A1:A2")

    If Not Intersect(target, Sheets(2).Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1:A2").Value = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A2").Value
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End sub
```

As usual, VBA's mind-numbingly opaque syntax is my downfall. Any advice in implementing the above simple task would be appreciated, as would referral to a VBA reference guide that is actually useful in explaining the hidden minutia of VBA.

Comment: An event handler in the sheet1 module will only respond to events in sheet1.  If you want to catch events in sheet2 then you need a handler in that sheet's code module.

Comment: _VBA reference guide that is actually useful_: you are already here...

Comment: I tried Ted's suggestion below without success. That is, I put the event handler in the sheet 1 code module. When the cells in sheet 1 change, the cells in sheet 2 do not change as expected. There must be a way.

Comment: Your title now contradicts the content of the question.  Please clarify which direction you want to copy: Sheet 1 to 2, or 2 to 1)

Comment: Sorry, corrected the title for ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you need to put the event handler in the sheet to be monitored.

`Worksheet_Change` will respond to changes made *by the user*.  If a cell changes for other reasons, eg a formula calculating, then this event is not called.

`Worksheet_Calculate` will respond the the sheet recalculating.  It has no concept of which cells on the sheet changed.  To use it in your use case, either copy the cells regardless and accept it will do some unnecassary copies, or track the values of `A1:A2` yourself to copy on change

Notes on your code:

- Unqualified references to `Range` refer to the worksheet your code is in.  So does `Me`.
- You can reference a sheets `CodeName` to to refer to a specific sheet regardless of what the user calls it or moves it.
- Trying to do an `Intersect` of ranges on different sheets makes no sence and will error
- `Sheets(1)` and `Sheet1` may not be the same worksheet.  The `Sheets` collection index is in the order the sheets are displayed in Excel, and can be changed by the user.

Here's a refactor of your code (put this in Sheets 1 module to copy changes on sheet 1 to sheet 2)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value <> Me.Cells(1, 1).Value Or _
       Sheet2.Cells(1, 2).Value <> Me.Cells(1, 2).Value Then

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Sheet2.Range("A1:A2").Value = Me.Range("A1:A2").Value
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, changes to a worksheet done by VBA code does trigger `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Just updated to match your title (body of question still says the oposite) And corrected typo in `If` statement

Comment: Chris, corrected body to match title. Tried your code and it works. Your explanation and comments have been very helpful for my better understanding of VBA event handler. Writing VBA functions has been no problem, but the event handler learning curve has been really steep for me. Tiny steps. Much thanks.